# python3 cryptography installation fails at screamingsnakecase

Tags: python, rust, pip, cryptography

I'm trying to install python cryptography, which seems to be needed for the current homeassistant.

**pip install cryptography** however crashes with the following messages:

```
Compiling Inflector v0.11.4

Running `rustc --crate-name inflector /home/ha/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1285ae84e5963aae/Inflector-0.11.4/src/lib.rs --error-format=json --json=diagnostic-rendered-ansi,artifacts,future-incompat --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,metadata,link -C embed-bitcode=no -C debug-assertions=off -C overflow-checks=on -C metadata=24d92325aeb54f99 -C extra-filename=-24d92325aeb54f99 --out-dir /home/ha/pip_tmp/pip-install-rlon2cnz/cryptography_70234a9f3a1d4c4e96ab4ab0fdb076c9/src/rust/target/release/deps -L dependency=/home/ha/pip_tmp/pip-install-rlon2cnz/cryptography_70234a9f3a1d4c4e96ab4ab0fdb076c9/src/rust/target/release/deps --cap-lints allow`
  error[E0583]: file not found for module `screamingsnakecase`
    --> /home/ha/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1285ae84e5963aae/Inflector-0.11.4/src/cases/mod.rs:22:1
     |
  22 | pub mod screamingsnakecase;
     | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     |
     = help: to create the module `screamingsnakecase`, create file "/home/ha/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1285ae84e5963aae/Inflector-0.11.4/src/cases/screamingsnakecase.rs" or "/home/ha/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1285ae84e5963aae/Inflector-0.11.4/src/cases/screamingsnakecase/mod.rs"

  error[E0432]: unresolved import `cases::screamingsnakecase::to_screaming_snake_case`
    --> /home/ha/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1285ae84e5963aae/Inflector-0.11.4/src/lib.rs:62:5
     |
  62 | use cases::screamingsnakecase::to_screaming_snake_case;
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `to_screaming_snake_case` in `cases::screamingsnakecase`

  error[E0432]: unresolved import `cases::screamingsnakecase::is_screaming_snake_case`
    --> /home/ha/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1285ae84e5963aae/Inflector-0.11.4/src/lib.rs:63:5
     |
  63 | use cases::screamingsnakecase::is_screaming_snake_case;
     |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `is_screaming_snake_case` in `cases::screamingsnakecase`

  Some errors have detailed explanations: E0432, E0583.
```

**Debug assistance** tells these are the components I'm using:

```
      Python: 3.9.2
      platform: Linux-5.10.0-20-rt-armmp-armv7l-with-glibc2.31
      pip: n/a
      setuptools: 66.0.0
      setuptools_rust: 1.5.2
      rustc: n/a
```

I've been searching the web for solutions but have not found anything useful. I've started this in a new *virtualenv* in and up-to-date debian 11. Installed *python3-cryptography*, freshly installed *rustc* but I've not been able to get past this point.

Has someone ran in the same dead end at SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE and is there a solution?

Comment: Weird, because Inflector 0.11.4 definitely does contain this file. Maybe try removing directory `~/.cargo/registry` then build again.

Answer (score 0):

@harmic, you probably were right. I found out that the files in .cargo had an older date. No idea how that happened. When I completely removed the entire virtual environment and all python related (hidden) directories and started completely anew, it completed the compilation and installation.
Thanks for the suggestion!